# Minor typo in /tags/{tag}/top-askers/{period}

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The discussion for the above method says "Returns the top 30 **answerers** active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days." It should be corrected as **askers**.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.